# Scheme intersection between lists of pairs

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following example of lists where on the first line I have a result and on the second a filter, and I need to keep only the results that match at least one of the pairs in the filter.

```
(((john . ?x) (new-york . ?city)) ((mike . ?x) (chicago . ?city)) ((mary . ?x) (london . ?city)))
(((new-york . ?city)) ((chicago . ?city)))

(((john . ?x) (new-york . ?city)) ((mike . ?x) (chicago . ?city)) ((mary . ?x) (london . ?city)))
(((john . ?x) (air-hockey . ?game)) ((mike . ?x) (tennis . ?game)))
```

The problem I'm having is that both the results and filter have a variable number of parameters and I don't know how to take out one element at a time for comparison. I could use some hints since this is a homework.

Match would mean in the first example john and mike since their cities match the filter. While in the second example it would just add each of the games they play to the result.

While you have to check each of the entries on the first line, for the `match` to work you would have to get #t for at least one of the entries on the second line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersect more lists in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851228/intersect-more-lists-in-scheme)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me from your question what "match" means in this context. Let me suggest that you probably first want to develop a helper function that accepts one element from the first line and one element from the second line, and returns "true" when they match.

Also, I would definitely write some test cases first :).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the same question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851228/intersect-more-lists-in-scheme), take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15852084/201359).